# Interrupter on induction heater

Tags: interrupts, induction, tesla-coil

Im currently trying to control the power of my induction heater, i want to use an interrupter to control it. but if i now interrupt the driver at random points, the mosfets wont turn off at zero voltage points, how would i go with building a comperator circuit that only interrupts at a zero crossing?

Comment: Show your circuit including coils and tning and power supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a current limited buck converter in front of your induction heater circuit .I have done this on a scientific experiment for heating a needle .This approach meant that ZVS was not disturbed .I think that it improves reliability so it is worth the cost and complexaty

Answer (score 0):

I went for a pulse density modulation approach after all, this meant that i had to use IGBTs because of the high impulse current.